# Fetching Data into from an API and assigning to Tom Select options

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, asynchronous

I have created a form and I am trying to add fetched data from an API to the options field.

Below is my web site link. I have put two different examples below each other. You can scroll down the page and be able to see what I mean.

I used this example code but it did not work.

```
new TomSelect("#makeField", {
sortField: {
field: "text",
direction: "desc",
},
});
```

https://pyro.design/

php code

```php
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom Page Template
 *
 * This is the template file for generic pages.
 * You can customize this file to fit your specific needs.
 *
 * @package Pyro
 */
get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part("template-parts/navigation"); ?>
<section class="pageDefault">
<form id="form__lead">

<label for="yearField">Select Year:</label>
  <select id="yearField" name="yearField" class="vehicleYear">
  <option value="">Select year</option>
    <option value="2024">2024</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
  </select><br/>

<label for="makeField">Select Make:</label>
  <select id="makeField" name="makeField" class="vehicleMake">
    <!-- Options go here -->
    <option value="">Select make</option>
  </select>
  
</form>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

JavaScript code

```js
import axios from "axios";
import TomSelect from "tom-select";
const yearField = document.getElementById("yearField");
const makeField = document.getElementById("makeField");
const modelField = document.getElementById("modelField");
let selectedYear = "";
new TomSelect("#yearField", {
  sortField: {
    field: "text",
    direction: "desc",
  },
});
// Event listener to update selectedYear when the year select field changes
yearField.addEventListener("change", function () {
  selectedYear = yearField.value;
  fetchData(); // Fetch data when the year is changed
});
function fetchData() {
  const apiEndpoint = `https://done.ship.cars/makes/?year=${selectedYear}`;
  axios
    .get(apiEndpoint)
    .then(function (response) {
      const data = response.data; // Assuming the response is an array of options
      populateDropdown(data, makeField);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      console.log("Response status:", error.response.status);
      console.log("Response data:", error.response.data);
    });
}
function populateDropdown(data, dropdown) {
  dropdown.innerHTML = "";
  const defaultOption = document.createElement("option");
  defaultOption.value = "";
  defaultOption.textContent = "Select make";
  dropdown.appendChild(defaultOption);
  data.forEach(function (item) {
    const option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = item.make;
    option.textContent = item.make;
    dropdown.appendChild(option);
  });
}
```

I am trying to load the data being fetched into the options field generated by Tom select js library. I am able to fetch the data but unable to assign it to the options fields dynamically.

Comment: It's not clear what "unable to" actually means in practical terms. Is there some sort of error - perhaps a JS console error, or a problem with the axios call? Or does it perhaps not return the data you expected? We have very little idea. Please do some simple debugging along those lines and narrow down the issue, then we can help you more easily

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. There is no problem with getting the data from api. My problem is implementing thst data into select fields via Tom select library. if you go to this website https://pyro.design/ you will see the code. Just scroll down and you will see two separate forms. You can see that the data is being fetched when you inspect the code

Comment: In the HTML for your site (pyro.desgin) you have duplicate`form__lead` IDs

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the *TomSelect* get a handle:

```
var make_select = new TomSelect("#makeField", {
    sortField: {
        field: "text",
        direction: "desc",
    },
});
```

Then after your AJAX call has been successfully executed (e.g. inside your *populateDropdown* function) clear all the previously set data first:

```
make_select.clearOptions();
```

and then inside the *forEach* add one option after the other using:

```
make_select.addOption({
    id: 4,
    title: 'Something New',
    url: 'http://google.com'
});
```

[Documentation](https://tom-select.js.org/examples/api/)